# How to change a specfic variable's name which repeat many times from one to another in R

Tags: r

I don't know the better title for my question... 
here is the problem.  the file name is "ad BW.CSV"  And in the code, I typed lots of "BW" since it is the variable name.

I want to change "BW" to "HB"(SO it will be more convinient to run the program).. But I think it's not the best way to just change it one by one.. 
Here is the example

```
data<-read.csv("ad BW.CSV")  #change "ad BW.CSV" to "ad HB.CSV"



boxplot(Bb$BW~Bb$SEX,                        #I want to change all of "BW" that apperaed in this script to "HB"...
        ylab = "ad BW", xlab = "Blarina brevicauda")  

boxplot(Sg$BW~Sg$SEX, 
        ylab = "ad BW", xlab = "Sorex gracilimus")

boxplot(Sc$BW~Sc$SEX, 
        ylab = "ad BW", xlab = "Sorex caecutiens")

boxplot(Sf$BW~Sf$SEX, 
        ylab = "ad BW", xlab = "Soriculus fumidus")
```

what shoudl I do? 
Thanks a lot~! I asked too many questions haha

Comment: I can copy this code to the word,and use the word function... But I am just wondering whether R has this kind of function~:)

Comment: Hi,Please share the sample data will be more useful to help you.

Comment: You should be using a programming editor or an IDE, such as Rstudio. Then your script can be modified with a global search and replace.

Comment: Another solution maybe to open your foobar.R script by Notepad++ for a search and replace. But take care - don't edit your filename.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry don't quite get it! You need to replace it in the script or the data?

If it's in the script, copy paste it into a notebook and then CTRL+H that opens the replace window. There you may choose options such as 'match case' etc.

If it's in the data then you can use a function or the library 'sqldf'. In this case you can provide an example and let us know of the data format.